# cocos2d touch move velocity

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, touch

i need to get the touch move velocity in cocos2d. any api for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic way of doing this is to do the following:

1. Of course,register a `CCLayer` with to be a touch event handler, and implement the touch begin, move and end functions.
2. Create in your relevant class, 2 `CGPoint` variables to store the `CURRENT` and `PREVIOUS` touch positions. Also create 2 `CCTIme` structures to store the `CURRENT` and `PREVIOUSLY` polled times.
3. Set up a schedule to update the current time (I've done this in the init of any relevant class.

i.e:

```
- (id)init {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        [self schedule:@selector(update:)];
        timeCURRENT = (ccTime)0;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)update:(ccTime)deltaTime {
    timeCURRENT += deltaTime;
}
```

4 . at the start of touch begin, set both the previous and current variables to the current touch location using the following:

```
-(BOOL) ccTouchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {  
 touchCURRENT= [touch locationInView: [touch view]];  
 touchPREVIOUS = touchCURRENT;
 timePREVIOUS = timeCURRENT;
...
```

Then, in touch moved, set the PREVIOUS to the CURRENT, and set the CURRENT using the same line of code as above

```
-(BOOL)ccTouchMoved:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {   
    touchPREVIOUS = touchCURRENT;
    touchCURRENT= [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    CGPoint deltaPosition = touchCURRENT - touchPREVIOUS;
    ccTime deltaTime = timeCURRENT - timePREVIOUS;
    timePREVIOUS = timeCURRENT;
```

> Velocity = deltaPosition/deltaTime.

Note that `CGPoint` subtraction may not work as advertised above, you may have to subtract individual members and feed them into a `CGPoint` factory method.

Comment: Thank you so much. it works now. btw, search "Fishes vs Birds" 2 weeks later, it's gonna be awesome!

Comment: my code here:prevPos = curPos;
 curPos = [MainScene locationFromTouches:touches];
 
 float xDif = prevPos.x - curPos.x;
 float yDif = prevPos.y - curPos.y;
 
 float distance = sqrt(xDif * xDif + yDif * yDif);
 
 ccTime deltaTime = curTime - prevTime;
 prevTime = curTime;
 
 float velocity = distance / deltaTime;

Comment: Exciting, and good to hear. On a side note, however, make sure you are pluralizing the word "Fish" correctly. The plural of fish is fish. It's only Fishes when referring to multiple varied species of fish.

Comment: well, that means tons of words to be change in my code. i do have different types of fish, but they are basically the same logic except the sprite image

Comment: Can i change the title of my app? is it my app id? i already registered Fishes vs Birds. and xcode code-signing is automatic. i created a profile before, but xcode made a team-profile for me with wildcard, that's not what i want

Comment: The title of the app is in its plist. Look in the 'Resources' group in XCode, there will be a .plift file their. One of the entries in there will let you set the title of the app that you see when it is installed on a device. Tis a minor gripe though, proper grammar isn't as popular as it should be ;]

Comment: you mean i don't have to change my app id? not found in the plist